# Ignore leading zeros in JOIN condition?

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to compare the field `bseg~zuonr` with `aufk~aufnr` in an inner join SQL select.

```
SELECT bseg~hkont, bseg~zuonr, bseg~belnr, bseg~gjahr, aufk~prctr FROM bseg INNER JOIN aufk
  ON bseg~zuonr = aufk~aufnr "<--
  WHERE bseg~hkont IN @s_hkont
  INTO TABLE @DATA(output).
```

This select is not working right for me and not giving back any data.

I think my problem is, that `aufk~aufnr` has leading zeros (for example: `000072667023`) and `bseg~zuonr` contains only the number without leading zeros (for example: `72667023`).

I have tried to use the [`TRIM`-function](https://help.sap.com/docs/HANA_SERVICE_CF/7c78579ce9b14a669c1f3295b0d8ca16/20f266137519101480abfc0aeb6c9dc3.html) inside the SQL select but that did not worked for me (Code snipped: `ON bseg~zuonr = TRIM( LEADING '0' FROM aufk~aufnr )` → `"(" is not allowed here. "." is expected.`)

Did I do something wrong? Do you know any solution for this issue?

Comment: If it has leading zeroes it appears to be a text-field.

Comment: bseg~zuonr is of type char(18) and aufk~aufnr is of type char(12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `concat` function. For example

```
SELECT bseg~hkont, bseg~zuonr, bseg~belnr, bseg~gjahr, aufk~prctr 
  FROM bseg 
  JOIN aufk ON concat( '0000', bseg~zuonr ) = aufk~aufnr
 WHERE bseg~hkont IN @s_hkont
  INTO TABLE @DATA(output).
```

Also you can combine this with `substring` to set the aufnr exact to 12 chars

Comment: it worth mentioning that this syntax is available only since 750

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM bseg JOIN aufk ON ( ltrim( aufk~aufnr, '0' ) = bseg~zuonr )
  FIELDS bseg~hkont, bseg~zuonr, bseg~belnr, bseg~gjahr, aufk~prctr 
  WHERE bseg~hkont IN @s_hkont
  INTO TABLE @DATA(output).
```

is also working